# Why is my swap<string,string> far slower than the std version?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

This is my C++ code:

```
inline static void swap(std::string& a1, std::string& a2) {    
    std::string temp( std::move(a1));
    a1 = std::move( a2 );
    a2 = std::move( temp );
}
```

I ran this function 1000000 times and it took 78ms on average, but the `std` one just took 13ms. I just looked at the implementation of `std::swap`, I found it just the the same as mine, so why is mine so slow?

Comment: The standard specializes `swap` for many standard types.  Normally this is so they can do things with the inner workings.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/swap2

Comment: *I ran this function 1000000 times and it took 78ms on average* -- Are you running a "debug", unoptimized build?

Comment: Maybe the `std::swap` specialization for `std::basic_string` is declared `friend` in your particular implementation of `std::basic_string`. This would cut out all the move assignment/move constructor calls by simply swapping the internal pointers and size/capacity counters. This could also happen by optimizing the `std::swap` call away into a `std::basic_string::swap` one.

Comment: The `std::swap` specialisation for `std::basic_string` probably just does `a1.swap(a2);`

Comment: Somewhat speculating, but with the short-string optimization the class likely isn't a POD. As a result, the code above may expand to consider 4 cases; a1 and a2 may both be short or long strings. Yet `std::string::swap` may very well be able to ignore the distinction and just swap the raw bytes regardless of their meaning. This of course is only possible because the `std` library implementation can make assumptions about the compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the standard *§21.3.2.8/p1 swap [string.special]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> ```
> template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
> void swap(basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>& lhs,
> basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>& rhs)
> noexcept(noexcept(lhs.swap(rhs)));
> ```
>
> <sub>1 **Effects: Equivalent to: `lhs.swap(rhs);`**</sub>

Consequently, `std::swap` specializes/has an overload for `std::string` and is equivalent as calling the member function `std::basic_string::swap`.

A possible implementation would be:

```
template<class Elem, class Traits, class Alloc> 
inline
void
swap(std::basic_string<Elem, Traits, Alloc>& left, 
     std::basic_string<Elem, Traits, Alloc>& right) noexcept(noexcept(left.swap(right))) {
  left.swap(right);
}
```

As for why your implementation is slower, my guess is that even if you move the one string to the another, the destructor for the temporary string will still be called. Something that is not the case in the STL compatible implementation above.